# Lazy Load + Isotope

Tags: lazy-loading, jquery-isotope

I've spent considerable amount of time trying to get isotope and lazy loading working together.

The issue: lazy loading works if the user scrolls down, however if the user uses the filters, the items show up on top but the images will not load.

Here is someone with the same issue, but it seems he fixed it. I tried several things but still couldnt get it working.

Here is the dicussion https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/issues/51

Thanks alot for your help

The code I am using is as follow.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#big_container .media_block img').each(function(index) {
        var item_height = $(this).attr("height");
        $(this).parent().parent().css("height",item_height);
    });
    $('#big_container').isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    layoutMode : 'masonry',
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 5,
    },
    sortBy : 'date',
    sortAscending : false,
    getSortData : {
        date : function ( $elem ) {
            return $elem.find('.date').text(); // Date format should be [Y-m-d H:i]
        },
        views : function( $elem ) {
            return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-views'), 10 );
          },
        //featured : function ( $elem ) {
        // return $elem.attr('data-featured');
        //  },
        rates : function( $elem ) {
            return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-rates'), 10 );
          },
        comments : function( $elem ) {
            return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-comments'), 10 );
          }
    }

    });

    $('#sort-by li a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents();
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
           $this.addClass('selected');
          var sortName = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
          $('#big_container').isotope({ sortBy : sortName });
          return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: As in your same question yesterday, it's difficult to fly blind - to provide a working answer without being able to see with devtools how things behave. Put up a jsfiddle or link to your online sandbox.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get isotope's sorting/filtering to work with lazyload you have to do the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $win = $(window),
        $con = $('#container'),
        $imgs = $("img.lazy");

    $con.isotope();

    $con.on('layoutComplete', function(){
        $win.trigger("scroll");
    });

    $imgs.lazyload({
        failure_limit: Math.max($imgs.length - 1, 0)
    });
});
```

### Explanation

According to the docs ( http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload )

> After scrolling page Lazy Load loops though unloaded images. In loop it checks if image has become visible. By default loop is stopped when first image below the fold (not visible) is found. This is based on following assumption. Order of images on page is same as order of images in HTML code. With some layouts assumption this might be wrong.

With an isotope sorted/filtered list, the page order is certainly different from the HTML so we need to adjust our `failure_limit`.

As you can see we store the jQuery object so that we can use its `length-1` as our failure_limit. If you're curious as to why it is `length-1`, it's because of the following check in lazyload's update method.

```
if (++counter > settings.failure_limit) {
    return false;
}
```

### Lazy load on other events

If you are not triggering your lazyloads on scroll, you will need to swap the "scroll" trigger for whichever event you are using.

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/arthurc/ZnEhn/

## Code for your site

I stored some of the jQuery objects in variables as they need to be re-used.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $window = $(window);
    var $images = $('#big_container .media_block img');
    var $big_container = $('#big_container');

    $images.each(function(index) {
        var item_height = $(this).attr("height");
        $(this).parent().parent().css("height",item_height);
    });


    $big_container.isotope({
        itemSelector : '.item',
        layoutMode : 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 5,
        },
        sortBy : 'date',
        sortAscending : false,
        getSortData : {
            date : function ( $elem ) {
                return $elem.find('.date').text(); // Date format should be [Y-m-d H:i]
            },
            views : function( $elem ) {
                return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-views'), 10 );
              },
            //featured : function ( $elem ) {
            // return $elem.attr('data-featured');
            //  },
            rates : function( $elem ) {
                return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-rates'), 10 );
              },
            comments : function( $elem ) {
                return parseInt( $elem.attr('data-comments'), 10 );
              }
        }

    });


    $big_container.on('layoutComplete', function(){
        $win.trigger("scroll");
    });

    $('#sort-by li a').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected') ) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents();
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
           $this.addClass('selected');
          var sortName = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
          $big_container.isotope({ sortBy : sortName });
          return false;
    });


    $images.lazyload({
        failure_limit : Math.max($images.length-1, 0);
    })
});
```

Comment: This was a big help to me. The top code sample is missing a final }) tho.

Comment: I cannot understand the reason why you used Math.max instead of just useing only $images.length-1. Could you please explain why? Thank you

Comment: anyone can explain the reason why for Math.max here?

Answer (score 0):

I used the next to fix lazy load for isotope:

```
let $isotope = $('#isotope').isotope();

$isotope.find('img').on('load', function () {
    $isotope.isotope('layout');
})
```

that's it.